# Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: debug is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am creating an Electron app. I have the following code in my `main.js` file:

```
if (debug) {
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.maximize()
  require('devtron').install()
}
```

When I run `npm run dev`, it shows error. Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
"name": "tiktok",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dev": "electron . --debug",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "Md Mazedul Islam Khan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "devtron": "^1.3.0",
    "electron": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to define the debug variable.

```
let debug = true;

if (debug) {
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.maximize()
  require('devtron').install()
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem @Jason. The debug should only true when I would `npm run dev`, not when `npm start` or `npm run` or this would open the DevTools all time. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe try process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

Comment: I found the fix @Jason. It would be like the following:

`const debug = /--debug/.test(process.argv[2])`